# Trigger a "tap" using value of AutocompleteInput in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I'm making a scatter plot of some data using Bokeh from a pandas dataframe (df). The dataframe is university data, and has columns "faculty_salary", "tuition", "sector" and "institution_name". The plot is faculty_salary vs tuition, and I'm using the sector to color the data, as shown below.

[image]

I currently have the tap tool which greys-out all other data points except for the one you clicked, as shown below.
 [image]

What I want to do is use the AutocompleteInput widget to select an institution_name from the autocomplete and have it highlight that data point by graying out all the others, just like the tap tool. The AutocompleteInput widget is working fine, it's just the code to make it highlight that data point that I'm struggling to figure out. Here's where I'm at:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
autocomp = AutocompleteInput(completions=df['name'].tolist())
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    what do I put here?? It doesn't seem to have a cb_obj
""")
autocomp.js_on_change('value',callback)
```

Please let me know how I can achieve the functionality I described: use the selected value in the AutocompleteInput to highlight the datapoint it corresponds to. I should note that for my application I would prefer a CustomJS solution, and not a Bokeh server solution.

**Edit**: It turns out that my browser (Chrome in Linux) doesn't recognize that an autocompletion value has been selected, but Firefox for Linux does. I think this must be because Jquery UI says:

*This widget manipulates its element's value programmatically, therefore a native change event may not be fired when the element's value changes.*

Suggestions for how to get around this in Bokeh are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Bokeh server solution :

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import AutocompleteInput
from bokeh.models.widgets import (Panel, Tabs, DataTable, TableColumn,
                                  Paragraph, Slider, Div, Button, Select)
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool,TapTool

def update_selected(wttr,old,new):
    a_val = autocomp.value
    names = source.data['names']
    ind = [i for i,x in enumerate(names) if x == a_val]
    source.selected={'0d': {'glyph': None, 'indices': []}, '1d': {'indices': ind}, '2d': {}}


data_dict = {'names':['test2','test3','hello','goodbye'],
           'x':[0,1,2,3], 'y':[10,20,30,40]}   
source = ColumnDataSource(data_dict)
autocomp = AutocompleteInput(completions=['test2','test3','hello','goodbye'])
autocomp.on_change('value',update_selected )
fig = figure(plot_width=400,
             plot_height=400,
             x_axis_label='x',
             y_axis_label='y',
             tools=["pan","hover","box_zoom","reset,save"])

fig.scatter('x','y',source=source)
layout = layout([[fig, autocomp]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

**EDIT : here is the solution using customJS**

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import AutocompleteInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS

data_dict = {'names':['test2','test3','hello','test3'],
           'x':[0,1,2,3], 'y':[10,20,30,40]}   
source = ColumnDataSource(data_dict)
fig = figure(plot_width=400,
             plot_height=400,
             x_axis_label='x',
             y_axis_label='y',
             tools=["pan","hover","box_zoom","reset,save"])

fig.scatter('x','y',source=source)
autocomp = AutocompleteInput(completions=['test2','test3','hello','goodbye'])
code = """
var autocomplete = cb_obj.value
var names = source.data.names
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] === val)
            indexes.push(i);
    return indexes;
}
var index = getAllIndexes(names,autocomplete)
source.selected = {'0d':{indices: [0]}, '1d':{indices: index},'2d':{indices: [0]}}
"""

callback = CustomJS(args={'source':source}, code=code)
autocomp.callback = callback
layout = layout([[fig, autocomp]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: I tried your solution by adding `show(layout)` at the end of your code (and adding output_file and show to the imports), then running it. It pulls up a plot and the autocomplete, but selecting a "completion" doesn't then highlight the data point. It's working for you?

Comment: I just tried it then and it seems to work fine. Are you using the second or first code? I think the first one requires bokeh serve. The second I just tried then and typed show(layout) and it is responding to a selection. Also what browser are you using? I only tested it in chrome

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Chrome as well. I'm literally just copying your code into a text editor, changing the line to `from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, output_file, show`, and adding `show(layout)` at the very end. I then run the file from a terminal using python 3.5, and it pulls up the plot in Chrome. The autocomplete works in  (although not nicely without adding the jquery ui snippet to the head of the html document), but selecting a completion doesn't have any effect on the graph...    I'm still new to Bokeh though, so hopefully I'm not forgetting some other step

Comment: Weird, I did the exact same thing, ran it from command line as well (just python nameoffile.py) and that works. What version of bokeh do you have installed? Try update it if its not up to date. And just to 100% clarify you are using the code with the customJS right?

Comment: Yeah sorry for not clarifying, I am using the CustomJS code. I wish we could make a JSfiddle easily, that solves these issues. I have Bokeh version 0.12.4

Comment: put in some console print statements of the variables, to see if it is picking up the index values when you select a completion. - try print out the values of "autocomplete", "names" and "index". if those are all working correctly, then print out the source.selected['1d'].

Comment: By the way, I put the output html into a google doc so you can see what it looks like for me: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12YY5PgEGTsGJkV6rf4XoWs0yip1nSgX9VpYJOvuT38M/edit?usp=sharing

And let me add that I *really* appreciate you helping me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137255/discussion-between-okonomiyaki-and-nscozzaro).

Comment: for me also selecting the auto completed choice does not complete it. I am on Chrome on Linux, tried Mozilla on my machine too, but it didn't help